# Moved disks to new computer, RAID won't re-assemble

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

I bought a new computer with a NVME ssd.I moved all the old disks over, but I couldn't get it to boot the old disks, so I tried just installing kubuntu on to the new machine's NVME.

After installing and booting, the RAID1 using two HDD isn't reassembling. I copied the mdadm.conf file from the original computer, but that didn't help. I tried `mdadm --assemble --scan` and it didn't do anything. I tried manually assembling a new RAID using the same disks, and it complains that neither has the right superblock.

Here's the results of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000VN008-2DR1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A83AC9A1-7D38-4D6D-8345-07790EE83C01

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1   2048 7814037134 7814035087  3.7T Linux RAID


Disk /dev/sdc: 3.7 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000VN008-2DR1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 05AC048C-ED0A-47DD-A95C-B5F4D0918414

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1   2048 7814037134 7814035087  3.7T Linux RAID
```

And the results of `mdadm --assemble /dev/md1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1`

```
mdadm: no recogniseable superblock on /dev/sdb1
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 has no superblock - assembly aborted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a `mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc` and re-created the RAID, and it automatically recognized the LVM physical volume on it and I was able to get all my data back.